# Changing an NG-Click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a button that calls a function. The function will load notes and show them in a span. Once the notes have been loaded, I want to change the function that gets called in `ng-click`. Below is my code.

```
$scope.loadNotes = function(id){
    $scope.span = document.getElementById("note" + id);

    $scope.span.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-4x fa-spin"></i>';

    $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "scripts/getTicketNotes.php",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCallback(res){
        $scope.span.innerHTML = res.data;
        document.getElementById("button" + id).setAttribute("ng-click", "hideNotes("+id+")");
        document.getElementById("button" + id).innerHTML = "Hide Notes";

    }, function errorCallback(res){

    });

};

$scope.hideNotes = function(id){
    $scope.spanNotes = document.getElementById("note" + id);

    if($scope.spanNotes.style.display == 'none'){
        $scope.spanNotes.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("button" + id).innerHTML = "Hide Notes";
    }else{
        span.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("button" + id).innerHTML = "Show Notes";
    }
};
```

The problem is that the button will still run the `loadNotes` function, even though the code inspector in Chrome says that the value of `ng-click` is `hideNotes()`. Not sure why it's doing that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ng-if directive in your HTML, using a flag value in your controller that gets set when you show your notes to toddle the element.

e.g.

```
<div ng-if="!notesShown" ng-click="loadNotes()">
<div ng-if="notesShown" ng-click="hideNotes()">
```

and in your conrtoller, set the notesShown value as required.

Comment: I took the premise of your answer and modified it. My solution is below. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks Cpt., glad it's all working! If you wouldn't mind, can you select it as your answer?

Comment: I will as it lead to my solution

Comment: Just an FYI, you should definitely use ng-if or ng-show to show/hide the elements in your view. Modifying the DOM directly from your controller is not considered good practice!

Answer (score 0):

When using angular you should not manipulate DOM elements the way you did in your code, declare an array of noteItems and use a repeater on the items.
for switching click functions declare two functions and switch between them:

```
var function1 = function(noteItem){
    $http({
       ....
    }).then(function successCallback(res){
       $scope.clickFunction = function2;
    }, function errorCallback(res){
    });
};
var function2= function(noteItem){
    $scope.clickFunction = function1;
};
$scope.clickFunction = function1;
```